# Fetch current location from local HTML5 page in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, geolocation

Hi I have a desktop app which creates a dynamic html page based on some criteria. My issue here is that, the html page which is created is saved locally(not hosted on server). I want to fetch current location of the user which executes that HTML file.

When I run the page in chrome browser file location is `file:///...`. The geolocation code doesn't seem to work, I did some research and it looks like there's some sort of security restriction in place in Chrome for using geolocation from a file:/// URI.

I cannot switch to any other browser not I can host the page on server as the page will be opened locally from android device.

Any help/solution would be appreciated.

Comment: From what I tried, I think it needs a `http` domain to request access from.

Comment: OK. So you mean there is no other way then hosting my page on the server? I could make a ajax call to the server and fetch the location but it will show the location of the server. I want location of the devide at the time of running my page.

Comment: If its anyways a file, you can hard code the location for time being.

Comment: @surajck I cannot harcode the location because the file will be opened on a android device(tablet). And my main concern is to take the location of the device at the time of opening that file